# PHP Curl realtime getinfo

Tags: php, file, curl

I'm trying to get Realtime info (Speed, Downloaded, Left) of File Downloads made by a script coded in PHP & Curl.

"curl_getinfo" gives all the required data but it gives it only after the download.

Anyway to get it realtime ?

Comment: Try curl multi, and http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do this with cURL. The `curl_multi_*` functions will let you make a number of asynchronous requests and check their current state, but only in so much as they will tell you whether they are completed/what their current errorlevel is.

You cannot get information about speed/downloaded/left from cURL. You would have to write your own HTTP request logic using [fsockopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) or similar, then you can include logic to update some kind of display somewhere as the request progresses. This does have the disadvantage of being much more difficult to make asynchronous - because of PHP's lack of multi-thread support you would have to use `exec()` or `pcntl_fork()` and make some kind of horrible IPC architecture.

I have done stuff like this before, and my honest opinion is that it is not worth effort. If you still want to go ahead and do it, I will dig out some of the stuff I used when I did it.